# VBA Excel providing formula to the cell only when the cell is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run the formula in the other cell, when my cell is clicked.
My code looks like this:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim answer As Integer
 Dim lrou As Long
 Dim c As Range, d As Range
 lrou = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
 If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AD3:AD" & lrou)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each d In Range("CA3:CA" & lrou)
        d.Value = "=NominatimGeocode(M" & lrou & ")"
        Next d
        For Each c In Range("B3:B" & lrou)
            If c.Value <> "Complete" And c.Value <> "Cancelled" Then
                answer = MsgBox("Do you want to create the Pre-Survey form?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "CST Tracker")
                    If answer = vbYes Then
                        Call Pre_Surveyform
                    Else
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
             Else
            Exit Sub
            End If
        Next c
    End If
  End If
 End Sub
```

and I am able to run the second part once the cell in the AD column is clicked. The problem occurs, when I try to run the formula for the cell in column CA being in the same row, in which the AD column is clicked. It looks like the loop is working for all the cells down to the last row. Excel is frozen and unresponsive.

How could I apply the formula just to the cell in column CA located only in the same row, in which the AD column is clicked?

Comment: `Target.EntireRow.Columns("CA")` is the cell in Col CA on the same row as `Target`    "It looks like the loop is working for all the cells down to the last row" - if you don't need the loop you can take it out?

Comment: Should it go instead of the For Each?

Comment: If you only need to think about the row you clicked on, why do you need any kind of looping?  I'm not sure what this code is for or what it's intended to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you intend this code to do, but if you're only interested in the clicked-on row then you could do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lrou As Long, status
 
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
 
    lrou = Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'in a worksheet code module, use Me to refer to the sheet
    If Intersect(Target, Range("AD3:AD" & lrou)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
    With Target.EntireRow
        .Columns("CA").Formula = "=NominatimGeocode(M" & Target.Row & ")"
        status = .Columns("B").Value
    End With
    
    If status <> "Complete" And status <> "Cancelled" Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to create the Pre-Survey form?", _
          vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "CST Tracker") = vbYes Then
            Pre_Surveyform
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have understood this step! Could you tell me what is the status for here?

Comment: `status` is the value from Col B.